# How do I bind Grid to xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to display a column filled with different titles. The thing is the amount of these titles is not previously defined, I thus cannot simply add textblocks in my .XAML from the beginning.

Here is the way I have tried to implement it, using a grid:

```
public Grid TitlesGrid { get; private set; }
TitlesGrid = new Grid(); 
TitlesGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    string title = "Title " + i.ToString();
    TextBlock newTitle = new TextBlock() { Text = title };

    TitlesGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

    Grid.SetColumn(newTitle, 0);
    Grid.SetRow(newTitle, i);

    TitlesGrid.Children.Add(newTitle);
}
```

Now it seems that the Grid is properly filled with the 5 (I set it to 5 here, but this number varies) textblocks, but I don't know how to bind it to the grid in the XAML. I have tried different things, as:

```
<Grid x:Name="TitlesGrid" Grid.Column="0"/>
<Grid x:Name="Titles" BindingGroup={Binding TitlesGrid} Grid.Column="0"/>
```

But none seem to work... So my question in two points is:

- How do I bind a grid object to a grid?
- Should I use a different class as grid for thius purpose?

I have been looking around for a long time now, and I don't find any helpful answer...

Comment: looks like you need ItemsControl which can generate items dynamically. "How do I bind a grid object to a grid?" - this make very little sense. the best you can have is insert TitlesGrid into a ContentControl: `<ContentControl Content="{Binding TitlesGrid}"/>`

Comment: An intentionally very simple implementation of an itemscontrol with add: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32164.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-2.aspx

Comment: some old questions which I answered which show ItemsControl in action: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612838/how-can-i-dynamically-lay-out-list-items-within-an-itemscontrol-using-a-grid,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145391/how-to-create-and-use-matrix-of-color-boxes-c-sharp-wpf, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097851/making-a-nxn-tic-tac-toe-gui-wpf-c-sharp

Comment: The ContentControl solution worked! Thank you so much!
I am still quite surprised there is no direct way to bind directly the grid, I'll go through the articles you propose to know more about it!

The thing is I am working with OxyPlot.PlotModel aside, and this can simply be bound to a PlotModel with Model={Binding myPlotModel}, so I thought I would be able to do the same here.

Comment: @I.Per, Model is a property of some control (Plot or PlotView, don't remember exactly). WPF bindings exist for to set properties. `<ContentControl Content="{Binding TitlesGrid}"/>` is an example of setting a property. But Binding can't *replace* entire parent element